# Why does the memory location for integers jump by 32 bytes?

Tags: python, macos

I created an experiment to test the memory allocation of a list of integers:

```
In [9]: [id(i) for i in range(10)]                                                                                
Out[9]: 
[4531258400,
 4531258432,
 4531258464,
 4531258496,
 4531258528,
 4531258560,
 4531258592,
 4531258624,
 4531258656,
 4531258688]
```

This seems to suggest that that each integer takes 32 bytes, but when I use `sys.getsizeof()`:

```
In [13]: [sys.getsizeof(i) for i in range(10)]                                                                    
Out[13]: [24, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28]
```

then the integers take less than 32 bytes.

Why is there is a difference?

Comment: `[id(i) for i in range(10)]` doesn't really tell you the size, although there is correlation. You are, in fact, just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A structure in memory can be 28 bytes long, and be allocated on 8-byte boundaries.  In a 64-bit processor, you want all pointers to be on 8-byte boundaries, so your 28-byte structures are allocated so that their start address are 32 bytes apart.

Comment: So list is a listed array?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "listed array"?

Comment: sorry, is it a linked array?

Comment: @riderdragon Maybe you mean linked list.  No, lists in Python are consecutive object references in memory, like arrays in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Alignment. All C structures are aligned so that some constraints are respected (they are specific to each processor, but basically, you want your types to be aligned with your memory bus size so that they get loaded with one access).

And in this case, you are aligned on 8 bytes (default for gcc for instance), so 28 bytes size gets "bumped" to 32 bytes actually used.

Comment: I cannot follow "you are aligned on 8 bytes", how is 8 figured out?

Comment: It's specific to the architecture and the compiler. For instance on x86_64 and gcc, it's 8 bytes (64 bits)